# What "good_new = p1[st==1]" means in Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow code in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, motion-detection, opticalflow

I'm using Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow algorithm in OpenCV to do some experiments, but I do not know what this code, `good_new = p1[st==1]`, means.

The official document to explain as "Select good points", but I do not know what to choose based on principles here. Here is the official part of the code:

```
while(1):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # calculate optical flow
    p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)
    # Select good points
    good_new = p1[st==1]
    good_old = p0[st==1]
    # draw the tracks
    for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
        a,b = new.ravel()
        c,d = old.ravel()
        mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
        frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
    img = cv2.add(frame,mask)
    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
    # Now update the previous frame and previous points
    old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
    p0 = good_new.reshape(-1,1,2)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: `st` is an array indicating status, in this case whether the pixels have been positively identified, in this case `1` means that it was found: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#cv.CalcOpticalFlowPyrLK so that line masks the pixels so it returns just the pixels that were identified

Comment: @ EdChum Thank you very much, I understand a little bit. But I still have a doubt: why the matrix p1 can use '[st==1]' this operation to extract elements.

Answer (score 2):

The array `st` is the same length as `p1` in the first dimension, so it can be used as a "mask" of sorts for how to select the values in p1

This example should assist with how `st==1` actually works:

```py
>>> st = np.asarray([1,0,0,1,0,1])
>>> p1 = np.reshape(np.arange(len(a)*2), [len(a), 2])
>>> p1
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])
>>> st==1
array([ True, False, False,  True, False,  True])
>>> p1[st==1]
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 6,  7],
       [10, 11]])
>>> p1[[True, False, True, False, True, False]]
array([[0, 1],
       [4, 5],
       [8, 9]])
```